# Getting message from topic like this,but only want the text message not all the information ,i have used jms listener and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

recive message isActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:WINMU250046-FMG-60272-1552990958996-1:1:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:WINMU250046-FMG-60272-1552990958996-1:1:1:1, destination = topic://testt1234, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1552990959592, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1552990959597, brokerOutTime = 1552990959600, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@11586f7b, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = Testing publisher}

Comment: You need to do some more work here and not just dump some log into the question.  Tell us what you did, show some code, explain how you got this output.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have all you want in the JMS API:

```
TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
String yourText = textMessage.getText();
```

But if you want to extract the text at String level, you just need to use `String.lastIndexOf()`  and `String.substring()` Methods:

```
String yourText = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf("text = ") + 7, msg.length() - 1);
```

I hope, i could help.

Comment: Would you please accept the answer? Just click on the grayed check mark besides the answer.